# OracleBulkCopy without auto commit

Tags: c#, oracle, bulkinsert

I want to delete older data and insert a new data, in same transaction, without dead time in which no information at all.

So, i want to delete data and insert a huge data in bulk insert.
Is it possible to use OracleBulkCopy's WriteToServer without commit?
I want to use same transaction and commit in the end of all methods, is it possible?

How would you advise me to do it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, since OracleBulkCopy does a direct path load, it will not be possible to do anything else to the table in that transaction.  Any attempt to do so, will result in:

`ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel`.

For lots more info, see here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15296_01/doc.111/e15167.pdf

and search for the section "Bulk Copy Support".